# How to utilise C# methods in a different programming language

Tags: c#, .net, dll, client-server, unmanaged

I am attempting to connect to a commercial server application, which only has a C# API.

I would imagine that the best approach for doing so would be to create a C# DLL - which is what I have done.  However, when examining the methods contained within the DLL utilising 3rd party tools, the methods do not seem to be visible.

I have searched extensively on StackOverflow, and found that [the following suggestion](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) works for most people - however the methods are still not visible when utilising this extension.

Thus it may be time to seek an alternate approach to how this problem can be solved - one option could be a C# console application.

Any ideas regarding what would be the best approach?

**EDIT:**

After running the DUMPBIN program, this is the output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>dumpbin /EXPORTS "C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Test.dll"

Dump of file C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Test.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        2000 .text
```

Comment: Could you give a sample of the method/class you are trying to build into C# Dll?

Comment: I tried the example shown in the link above, which didn't work either. The classes are not visible when opening the DLL in DependencyWalker.

Comment: What does dumpbin say?

Comment: @doctorlove - edited the question with DUMPBIN output

Comment: Maybe you can use [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) to integrate the functionality of your C# library into the Basic+ application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Basic+ has an option to call C code, you have an option to create a project in Managed C++:

[image]

Exports some function decorated like:

```
    extern "C"{
    __declspec(dllexport) void _cdecl MyFunction()
     {
          _MyImpl(); //see below wy this
      }
    }

void MyImpl()
{
    MyCSharpObj^ test = gcnew MyCSharpObj()...
    test->Methods(...
}
```

Outside of the portion decorated with extern C you can safely call and **mix** managed and unmanaged calls. The reason you should go outside the extern C block is that almost all managed function have overloads, and Extern C does not support method overloading even in call. 
You can call c# by just adding references ( actually you can write all your code in managed C++, but is not so friendly ) to your .NET libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Basic+ seems to be made by [Revelation Software](http://www.revelation.com/).

On [this page](http://www.revsoft.co.uk/revelation_software_history.aspx), it says:

> OpenInsight 9.1 released
>
> This new OpenInsight release included a
>   couple of .NET innovations. NetOI enables developers to code using
>   their Microsoft Visual Studio licenses and work against an OpenInsight
>   database. **The RevDotNet functionality provides a method of calling
>   .NET APIs** and using the .NET controls within an OpenInsight
>   application.

Can you use RevDotNet to call your C# APIs directly?